# Extracting the Data using python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hey Guys I have automated the script to extract the content from the site below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import urllib2
import requests
import sys
import re, clr
import csv
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from ast import literal_eval
import shorten

chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/")  # opening the site
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    """//*[@id="adminForm"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/div[2]/label""").click()  # click the radio button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="coordinate_address"]""").click()  # clicking the textbox
cities = [' Aguila,Arizona']  # city list
for city in cities:
    # print (city)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="coordinate_address"]').send_keys(city)  # passing cities
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="adminForm"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/button').click()
x = driver.current_url
# print x
Data = {'optionCoordinate': '2', 'coordinate_address': cities}
page = requests.post(x, data=Data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'span5'})
data = []
new_list = []

def remove_from_list(l, x):
    new_list = [li.replace(x, '') for li in l]
    return new_list

def flatten(iterable):
    result = []

    for item in iterable:
        try:
            item_eval = literal_eval(item)
            if not isinstance(item_eval, list):
                raise ValueError()
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.extend(flatten(item_eval))

    return result


def shorten(s, subs):
    i = s.index(subs)
    return s[:i + len(subs)]


csvList = []

for li in div.find_all('li', limit=6):
    extracted_data = li.get_text().encode("ascii", "ignore")
    data = extracted_data.split(":")
    data = remove_from_list(data, u'\xa0')
    data = remove_from_list(data, u'\r')
    data = remove_from_list(data, u'\n')
    #csvList.append(str(data))
    if len(data) is 2:
        print str(data[1])
        csvList.append(str(data[1]))
    else:
        print str(data[1:3])
        csvList.append(str(data[1:3]))
csvList = flatten(csvList)
csvList = [str(csvList[x]) for x in range(len(csvList))]
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(csvList[0], '%B %d, %Y').date()
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(str(datetime_object), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
print datetime_object
csvList[0] = str(datetime_object)
csvList[4] = re.sub("\D","",csvList[4])
csvList[6] = re.sub("\D","",csvList[6])
#head, sep, tail = csvList[5].partition('Any')
#csvList[5] = head
csvList[5] = shorten(csvList[5], 'Load')

#del csvList[4]
print csvList
with open('/home/priyanka/Desktop/output.csv','w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(csvList)

driver.close()
```

This code will extract the contents. But what i need is based on **Elevation :
2170.4 Feet** content 
it should take only **Elevation ≤ 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is 0 psf**
out of those three.

Elevation ≤ 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is 0 psf

Elevation > 3,000 and ≤ 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is 5 psf

Elevation > 4,500 and ≤ 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is 10 psf

So Basically based on Elevation value it should compare with Elevation  feet and take the respective Content

Finally the output should look like

**['01/09/17', ' Aguila,Arizona', '33.9428069', '-113.1740805', '21704', '  ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load', '0']**

**Please help me guys. Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: where is your script failing/ what is the problem area?

Comment: I don't see your code doing anything around those lines? It is as good as asking someone else to write that part of the code